# Как узнать количество строк в каждой таблице по классам?

Tags: jquery, html

Есть вот такая таблица:

```
<table class="mable">
<tr class="t"><td>4</td></tr>
<tr class="t"><td>3</td></tr>
<tr class="t"><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="t"><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

и через js при загрузке добавляю к каждому строку номера строк по убыванию :

```
tr=$('.mable tr.t').length;
//alert(tr);
//tr=0;
$('.t').each(function(){

            $(this).append('<div class="tr-number">'+tr+' эт.</div>');
            tr--;
            });
```

Код работает как надо.

Но если эта таблица одна. [Если таблиц несколько](http://jsfiddle.net/9HyfN/8/), то неправильно показывает.
Короче, незнаю как получить доступ к строку таблицы через `$(this)` внутри `each();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Смотрим пример в действии](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/7PMnZ/1/)

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="t"><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr class="t"><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr class="t"><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr class="t"><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
<table class="table">
    <tr class="t"><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr class="t"><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr class="t"><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr class="t"><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr class="t"><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr class="t"><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('.table').each(function(){
    var row = $('.t', this);
    var numRows = row.length;
    row.each(function(){
        $(this).find('td').append('<div class="tr-number">' + numRows + ' эт.</div>');
        numRows--;
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо @Deonis, но без find получился:
$(this).append('<div class="tr-number">' + numRows + ' эт.</div>');
а row с 0 начинаеться ?

Comment: Я же вам [ссылочку на пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/7PMnZ/1/)

Comment: сорри, ошибка у меня ,поправил :)

Answer (score 3):

попробуй пройтись циклом по самим таблицам, а уже в цикле находить нужные ячейки

```
$('table').each(function(){
    var tr = $(this).find('tr');          
});
```

Comment: спасибо, но ответ @Deonis -a полностью удовлетворяет меня))

Comment: да ничего страшного, я нет переживаю